# Is there a way to return to view from after saving record

Tags: 2013

Would it be possible (or difficult) to have the screen view return directly to the “view form” after entering or modifying it in the “ edit form” or at least have the option to do so upon saving any given form?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to set it up in a page or email hyperlink. (I.e. the ribbon's edit item link won't do this for you out of box).

Add the following to the end of the edit.aspx link:

`&source=https://host.sharepoint.com/sites/redirectsite`

Comment: where would I put that link?

Comment: You can put the hyperlink as an additional column on your list. It could be a calculated column.

Your url string should look something like:

https://host.sharepoint.com/sites/testsite/lists/edit.aspx?ID=%ID_Column%&source="https://host.sharepoint.com/sites/redirectsite"